# How to get Libsodium running on Alpine Java

Tags: java, docker, java-native-interface, libsodium

I am trying to run Libsodium on the Alpine Java docker image.

```
 RUN "apk update && apk upgrade"
 RUN "apk add --no-cache ca-certificates wget && update-ca-certificates"
 RUN "apk add --no-cache openssl build-base libffi libsodium"
```

But when I run the container, Java crashes.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0f25b65ceb, pid=22, tid=0x00007f0f265f7700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so+0x1fceb]  __vdsosym+0x9
#
# Core dump written. Default location: //core or core.22
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid22.log
```

What dependencies are required to run libsodium?

Comment: Are you talking abou tthis alpine java image? (https://hub.docker.com/r/anapsix/alpine-java/)

Comment: @VonC  https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8/

Comment: Can you try with https://hub.docker.com/r/anapsix/alpine-java/ ?

Comment: @VonC I am still getting the error with 8_jdk image tag. Is this a JNI error?

Comment: It shouldn't be. More some kind of JRE incompatibility.

Comment: @VonC you are right.  i need to use the oracle jre unlimited version if i want strong encryption.  i switched to open-jdk and the error disappeared. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use OpenJDK or OracleJDK *unlimited*

Comment: Nice catch, well done +1. What docker image did you use?